# How to execute 'su' command using parallel-ssh

Tags: python, linux, stdin, root, parallel-ssh

I want to log in to two hosts using [parallel-ssh](https://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.1/index.html) and execute `su` command. Then I want to confirm that I am the root user by printing out `whoami`

Code:

```
hosts = ['myHost1', 'myHost2']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='myUser', password='myPassword')

output = client.run_command('su')

for host in output:
    stdin = output[host].stdin
    stdin.write('rootPassword\n')
    stdin.flush()

client.join(output)

output = client.run_command('whoami')

for host, host_output in output.items():
    for line in host_output.stdout:
        print("Host [%s] - %s" % (host, line))
```

Result:

```
Host [myHost1] - myUser
Host [myHost2] - myUser
```

Obviously, I expect root in the output. [I am following the documentation.](https://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.1/advanced.html#run-command-features-and-options)

I've tried using all different line endings instead of `\n` and nothing has changed. 
How can I execute `su` command using `parallel-ssh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what I am trying to do is not achievable.

**The first problem**

I found in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parallelssh/LGs64wcIssY) that all commands are in their own channel. That means that even if `su` would be successful it wouldn't affect the second command. The author of the post recommends running

```
su -c whoami - root
```

**The second problem**

I managed to debug the problem even further by changing `host_output.stdout` to `host_output.stderr` It turned out that I receive an error which previously was not being shown on the terminal:

```
standard in must be a tty
```

Possible solutions to this problem are [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/397031/run-script-as-another-user-from-a-root-script-with-no-tty-stdin) . They didn't work for me but might work for you.

For me workaround was to allow on all my hosts root login. And then in parallel-ssh I log in as a root already with all the rights in place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
**def exec_command(hosts):
    strr = ""
    client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='admin', password='admin_password')
    cmd = 'echo root_password |su -c "commmand" root'
    output = client.run_command(cmd)
    client.join()
    for host_out in output:
    for line in host_out.stdout:
        strr+=line+" "
    return strr
    **
```

***'echo root_password |su -c "command" root'***

Answer (score 0):

try to put `sudo=True` at the end of `run_command`

```
output = client.run_command(<..>, sudo=True)
```

like in [docs](https://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.1/advanced.html#run-with-sudo)

Comment: There are some key differences between su and sudo. I want to execute su command.

Comment: @kukis to enter in `su` `superuser` you need to do `sudo su` and password

Comment: sudo su doesn't work because for myUser I receive "Sorry, user myUser is not allowed to execute '/bin/su' as root on myHost."
Simply, myUser is not in the group that can execute sudo. I need to log in as root (using root password, not myUser's password)